# How to find selected node in Tree?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have dynamic tree (moreover nodes can have children). Every node has some action. When I right click on some node, it offers me some actions. One action, for example createChildNode creates child node, which in turn creates MyObject2. MyObject2 must be created with assistance of MyOject1, which was created in parent node(that one where I right click for actions ).

How to get that object from selected node? That objects in nodes are putted to lookups.singleton(MyObjectX)

Answer (score 2):

If your tree only accept single selection then it should be possible with:

```
tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
```